# Como obtengo un archivo en JS y lo envio a ASP.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net

Buen dia. Estoy trabajando con C# y ASP.Net del lado del servidor y con JS y html del lado del cliente.

Tengo un formulario similar a esto

```
<form id='frmForm'>
<label>Subir Archivo</label>
<input type ='file' id='file' />
<button>Guardar</button>
</form>
```

lo que yo quiero es obtener el archivo mediante js y enviarlo a mi servidor por medio de AJAX como un parámetro mas pues en realidad envío varios campos mas.

si me podrían orientar sobre como hacer esta función, tanto del lado del cliente y como que tipo de dato lo recibo del lado del servidor

Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero hay varias cosas que debe hacer en el servidor:
1. Definir un control de tipo archivo asi
   
2. Debe crear un botón que llame una función JavaScript que se encarga de 
   De seleccionar el archivo y llamar la función Ajax.
   Try it
3. Debe definir la función JavaScript, algo como esto:
   
      function LoadFile() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myFile");
     }
   
4. En la función debe definir el Ajax que se comunique con el la función en el servidor.

Por ejemplo:
En el cliente puede ser algo como esto:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#btnUploadFile').on('click', function () {

                var data = new FormData();

                var files = $("#fileUpload").get(0).files;

                // Add the uploaded image content to the form data collection
                if (files.length > 0) {
                    data.append("UploadedImage", files[0]);
                }

                // Make Ajax request with the contentType = false, and procesDate = false
                var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "UploadPage.aspx",
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: data
                });

                ajaxRequest.done(function (xhr, textStatus) {
                    // Do other operation
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

En el servidor puede ser algo como esto:

```js
public partial class UploadPage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var httpPostedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["UploadedImage"];
            if (httpPostedFile != null)
            {
                var fileSavePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles"), httpPostedFile.FileName);

                // Save the uploaded file to "UploadedFiles" folder
                httpPostedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ooooo muchas gracias. ha sido de gran ayuda